# How do I use a variable to add keys to a javascript Hashmap ?

Tags: javascript

```
// Create the hashmap
var animal = {};
// Add keys to the hashmap
animal[‘cat’] = { sound: ‘meow’, age:8 };
animal[‘dog’] = { sound: ‘bark’, age:10 };
animal[‘bird’] = { sound: ‘tweet’, age:2 };
animal[‘cow’] = { sound: ‘moo’, age:5 };
```

I'm using the code above to try and create a hashmap. My question is, where sound and age are placed, how would I place them in using a variable.

For example

```
var one = 'sound';
var two = 'age';
animal['cat'] = {one: 'meow', two: 9};
```

Comment: Also: Use the correct quotes, `"` or `'`, not `‘`. (You could also use a template literal, but no need in the above.)

Answer (score 0):

In ES2015+ it's

```
var one = 'sound';
var two = 'age';
animal['cat'] = {[one]: 'meow', [two]: 9};
```

Run it through a transpiler e.g. [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/) and you get

```
var _animal$cat;

var one = 'sound';
var two = 'age';
animal['cat'] = (_animal$cat = {}, _animal$cat[one] = 'meow', _animal$cat[two] = 9, _animal$cat);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var animal = {};
var one = 'sound';
var two = 'age';

animal['cat'] = {};
animal['cat'][one] = 'meow';
animal['cat'][two] = 9;

console.log(animal);
```